# How to wait for function end before viewDisappear?

Tags: swift, ios9, completionhandler

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    var done = false
    updateCurrentUserInDB(self.currentUser, onCompleted: { done = true })
    while !done { }
}
```

Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: just do the navigation or redirection at the end of that function or after the completion .

Comment: @sourav: sorry but what do you mean? Which navigation or redirection, and which function?

Comment: Waiting in a lifecycle callback is never a good idea. Why do you need to do it?

Comment: @DanieleBernardini: because I need that the update (rest api call) to be done before the end of the view.

Comment: That is what I am asking ;-) why do you need to do it. There might be other solutions, like using a NSOperationQueue where you can update the user and do, later on, whatever you needed that update for.

Comment: It is updateSettings view. After coming back in main view I read user informations in DB so I need the update to be completed. Any example to manage it with NSOperationQueue?

Comment: I am on the run at the moment so I cant write an example for you, but if that is the reason I would use the `NSNotificationCenter` to advertise that the user update was successful and then refresh the data in the main view when you receive this notification.

Comment: @DanieleBernardini: thank you for this idea, I will implement it to improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why is your updating take so long?

A good approach is to update the data continuously while the user is making changes. If you have a "Cancel" button you need to implement something to rollback.

Anyway, if you can't make the saving process any faster i would recommend forwarding the user object to the main view, updating the user there (while showing a progress indicator) and reload the main view inside the completion block.

Edit: A better approach would be to pass the data back to the main view (see above), use that data to update the main view and sync with your backend in the background. that way the user doesn't have to wait until syncing is completed + you don't have to make a separate request to the backend asking for the same data you just sent to it.

Comment: Maybe because it is a call to a rest api on a remote server? On the backend, I use node.js and mongodb.

Comment: I see, no offense. your method name suggested something local...
so i would take my other approach then, pass the data to the main view, sync it with your backend and reload the view